# Can a raspberry beacon retrieve any data

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

I want to build a BLE Beacon with Raspberry Pi Zero W and with an iOS and Android app (which I'll develop) I'll list the beacons and select one to send 4-6bytes of data to trigger some action on the Pi. Is that possible with Beacons or should I use something else. I am writing in Go and I don't want to pair the devices.

Comment: You want to send data from the phone to the beacon/pi?

Comment: You might find the following article of interest: https://towardsdatascience.com/spelunking-bluetooth-le-with-go-c2cff65a7aca

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to make a Raspberry Pi Zero W scan for beacons and take action which identifier it saw. (Although please note that this must be a Zero W.  The base Raspberry Pi Zero does not have wireless functionality.)

You won't find beacon detection code in Go on the Raspberry Pi, so your best bet is to use a native C program to do the beacon scanning part, and call it as a shell script from your Go program.  The following C program is one I use on a Raspberry Pi to scan for beacons:

https://gist.github.com/davidgyoung/0a18028b4338ff6cb201fba274502662

That program must be compiled on the Raspberry Pi with `cc scanner.c -lbluetooth -o scanner`, after which you can start the scanner with just `scanner`.  The output of the program will be something like this:

```
B8:27:EB:1F:93:4D -68 02 01 06 11 06 82 75 25 D9 37 9D D7 8F 5F 4A F4 20 00 00 75 30
71:5C:23:9D:BC:7F -68 02 01 1A 02 0A 0C 0B FF 4C 00 10 06 03 1A 3B D4 B2 EB
B8:27:EB:1F:93:4D -68 02 01 06 11 06 82 75 25 D9 37 9D D7 8F 5F 4A F4 20 00 00 75 30
4A:53:7F:64:71:EC -91 03 03 9F FE 17 16 9F FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
69:0D:FF:7B:75:65 -73 02 01 1A 02 0A 0C 0A FF 4C 00 10 05 03 1C 27 BB 63
61:39:71:E9:1D:C9 -93 02 01 1A 02 0A 18 0A FF 4C 00 10 05 01 18 3B 24 12
B8:27:EB:1F:93:4D -68 02 01 06 11 06 82 75 25 D9 37 9D D7 8F 5F 4A F4 20 00 00 75 30
```

Each line above shows the MAC address of the detected bluetooth device, followed by the signal strength RSSI, then the hex bytes of the advertisement.

Your Go program will need to read each line of the output of `scanner` then parse the bytes of the advertisement to look for beacon patterns to perform various functions when it sees a packet with a certain byte pattern (indicating that a mobile phone sent out that packet.)

Comment: I wasn't clear enough I guess, I want to make Raspberry a broadcaster but at some point, collect data from receivers(phones).